# Android app that connects to IIS website using windows authentication

Tags: android

I have started playing with developing apps for the android. I have a site hosted on an IIS server that uses Windows authentication. I want to connect to it through my app. When I access the site from a computer or phone it prompts for the username and password. However, I cannot get the webview to pop up the credentials prompt, nor have I been able to pass the username and password to the site in my Main_Activity when using the emulator (target 4.4 API 19).

I have been working on this for a while looking a tons of examples. It's difficult to relate the code I have seen to my specific situation, I have copied and pasted number examples. I keep getting 401 unauthorized when the page comes up.

I am trying to stick with the android app thing this time, so any help would be greatly greatly appreciated. Below is my last attempt:

Here are 2 methods I have created or modified. There are seperate from one another.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("URL:8080/");

    }
```

"More code.."

```
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest (WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm){

            String[] up = view.getHttpAuthUsernamePassword("username", "password");
            if( up != null && up.length == 2 ) {
                handler.proceed(up[0], up[1]);
            }
        }

}
```